# Apache camel parallel processing

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, apache-camel

I am working on an apache camel to read data from MySQL DB and push it to Kafka. I have built the router which works fine but to tune it for max performance I want to do run Kafka activity ( to ) in parallel. My program is pooling 500 records from DB and publishing them to Kafka. How to run Kafka publish part in parallel. Do I need to use multicast, but I have only one target endpoint to produce.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    String update = "update inv set issync = 'T' where gtx= :#gt";
    String select ="select * from inv where issync= 'F'";
    from("sql:"+select+"?dataSource=#dataSource&maxMessagesPerPoll=500&onConsume="+update)
            .process(new InventoryProcessor())
            .log("${body}")    // do i need multicast for parallel 
            .to("kafka:item_k?brokers=localhost:9092"); //  how to make this parallel 
}
```

I tried making a split and parallel processing but from sql component itself  one by one message is passed to below function even maxMessagesPerPoll=500 . I was assuming 500 rows will be fetched from table and all 500 will be available in below lines to split and process parallelly.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    String update = "update inv set issync = 'T' where gtx= :#gt";
    String select ="select * from inv where issync= 'F'";
    from("sql:"+select+"?dataSource=#dataSource&maxMessagesPerPoll=500&onConsume="+update)
             .log("${body}")
             .split(body())
             .parallelProcessing()
            .process(new InventoryProcessor())
            .log("${body}")    // do i need multicast for parallel 
            .to("kafka:item_k?brokers=localhost:9092"); //  how to make this parallel 
}
```

Comment: Split the query results using the split EIP and seach each split item to your kafka endpoint

Comment: on what parameter i can split query result could you share documentation to know  split EIP

Comment: After split do I need to say parallel processing